# PHPmyadmin connect to remote server

Tags: mysql, apache, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

Here is my configuration to connect remote server

```
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']          = '<IP>';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']          = '3306';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket']        = '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type']  = 'tcp';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']     = 'mysql';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress']      = FALSE;
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'config';  
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = 'root';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = 'pass';
```

1)Port 3306 open to all traffic.

2)Tried with clear the cookie

3)Tried with restart apache

Still i am getting this error message

```
#2002 - Connection refused
The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
```

Comment: contact the remote ip's admin.

Comment: i've the access to server